# Unknown kitchen tap aerator needed

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink

I need a new aerator for this kitchen tap, but I can't identify the correct type required.

I have a standard fitting that fits the thread, but it doesn't interface with the narrow pipe directly like the old aerator (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B08DLWHCD5). This appears to be required, as otherwise water leaks from the thread (there's no where for the normal seal to go in this spout, as the pipe is at an angle).

Is this a standard type of fitting?

[image: picture of underside of spout]

[image: old aerator, view of top]

Comment: You probably need to know the brand and model number of the faucet. Do you have the old aerator? Perhaps it can be modified, or used to assist in finding a replacement.

Comment: I've added a picture of the aerator. No branding visible I'm afraid.